# Formatting Date Using Google Charts and Epoch

Tags: date-format, google-visualization, epoch, timezone-offset

I have an epoch 1362873600 and I only care about the date portion, not the time.

My goal is to get:
03/10/13

I'm doing the following:

```
var dateFormatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({formatType: 'short'});
dateFormatter.formatValue(epochValue);
```

I've tried with epochValue as a string and as an int.

Both yield: Object 1362873600 has no method 'getTimezoneOffset'

Is there perhaps an option I can use to ignore the timezone part? What is it that formatValue is expecting that would have this getTimezoneOffset method? The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#formatters) just says 'value'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `formatValue` is expecting a `Date` object.  You can construct one if you know the epoch with `new Date(epoch)`.  After you create that object, you should be able to pass it to `formatValue` and get the value you're expecting.

```
var dateFormatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({formatType: 'short'});
var result = dateFormatter.formatValue(new Date(epochValue));
```